# Moving time formatting process to a function to pass over multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, time

This is mostly a question about moving a multi-step process to a function more elegantly. I am working with a large hydrology time series were the date and time, designated as a column named "dts", are imported as a column with a character format and looks like this:

dts 
10/1/1992 0:00 
10/1/1992 1:00 
10/1/1992 2:00 
...

And so on. I want to move this to a as.POSIXct format which I do long-form this way:

```
df$dts <- strptime(as.character(df$dts), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df$dts <- as.POSIXct(df$dts,)
df$dts <- floor_date(df$dts, "hour")
```

This works great and gets the desired result. But I don't want to copy and paste and rewrite this over as I want to learn to be more efficient at coding. So I tried to then move this to a function:

```
timeformat <- function(x) {
  strptime(as.character(x), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  as.POSIXct(x,)
  floor_date(x, "hour")
}

df$dts <- lapply(df$dts, timeformat)
```

When I do that, I get the common error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Interested in tips or guidance on which way to go with this. Thanks.

Comment: Why you have to use `lapply` here?  It seems like a single dataset.  Shouldnt `timeformat(df$dts)` work?.  Also, I think the `timeformat` function needs `x` to assign. i.e. x<- strptime(as.character(x),...` and for the second line also

Comment: I was following the formatting of a different post focused on applying a function to specific columns within a data frame. Running it as suggested still yields the same error though.

Comment: You've forgotten to assign the result of `strptime()` to anything...

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I had tried assigning previously and gotten a different error, but that's because I was using `lapply` still. If I combine both answers it works. Thanks guys for clearing this up!

Answer (score 2):

Reformatted thanks to akrun and hadley:

```
timeformat <- function(x) {
  x <- strptime(as.character(x), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  x <- as.POSIXct(x,)
  x <- floor_date(x, "hour")
}

df$dts <- timeformat(df$dts)
```

One day I shall learn functions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but, Working with dates gets easy if you use the "lubridate" package. Base R's functions can give trouble sometimes.